# Show multiple marker titles on Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I successfully added multiple markers on the map. Using the `showInfoWindow` only shows the title of the last added marker. so is there a way to show all the markers' title at once?
Thanks :)

Comment: can you please elaborate your question so that other can understood what is your exact requirement. as I understood your question showInfoWindow only shows the title of last added marker? google map will shows info dialog of particular marker that you are selected but not others information dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to directly show all info windows.

I'd suggest to use custom marker icon and Canvas to draw your text above the marker which could look like info window.

Comment: Perfect, but do you have any idea how could I implement such a thing?

Comment: I have some code that could help you. It draws numbers on marker image: [DemoIconProvider.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions-demo/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/demo/DemoIconProvider.java).

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_dialog, null, false);
tv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());

tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy);

BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);

BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy)).title("origin").snippet("Srivastava").icon(icon));
// Showing the current location in Google Map
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("destination").snippet("Srivastava").icon(icon));
```

Comment: Define your custum layout with image view and textview to show image and name of place or person... in marker_dialog above layout

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is the functionality of `Google Map API V2`, only one `InfoWindow` is shown at any given time.